# Remove Fields from ES

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, hashmap, kibana

I am getting the following error on ES:

```
[Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=Limit of total fields [1000] in index [<index_name>] has been exceeded]]
```

I don't want to increase the field size, since it can cause memory explosion. After going through a lot of solutions on stack overflow, I found that we need to create a back up index, which I created like this:

```
PUT /<dest_index>
```

Now, I need to copy data from existing index and to the new one created above, while removing the unwanted field.

So, i tried this:

Created a pipeline for removing the field:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/removePropertyMap
{
  "description": "Removes the 'propertyMap' field", 
  "processors": [
    {
      "remove": {
        "field" : "propertyMap"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And, I am copying data like this:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "<source_index>"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "<dest_index>",
    "pipeline": "removePropertyMap"
  }
}
```

After this, i still see propertyMap as a field in the mapping of the new index.

I am checking the mapping through:

```
GET <dest_index>/_mapping
```

Now the field which I want to delete looks like this:

```
"project": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
        }
    }
},
"properties": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
        }
    }
},
"propertyMap": {
    "properties": {
        "90001": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
        },
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the same document structure:

```
{
    "<index>": {
        "mappings": {
            "_doc": {
                "properties": {
                    "propertyMap": {
                        "properties": {
                            "field1": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "field2": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "anotherField": {
                                        "type": "text",
                                        "fields": {
                                            "keyword": {
                                                "type": "keyword",
                                                "ignore_above": 256
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inside properties there are a huge number of other fields as well, same as field 1 and field 2.

What am i doing wrong in this?

Comment: Good start! Is `propertyMap` located at the root level of your documents?

Comment: @Val No, propertyMap is not the root, it has other elements at the same level. I have update the structure in my question above.

Comment: By "being at the root-level", I meant whether `propertyMap` wasn't include into another englobing structure. Can you show a sample document? Have you tried to [simulate your pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/simulate-pipeline-api.html) with a sample document ?

Comment: Added a sample document above.

Comment: I made few changes in my pipeline: PUT _ingest/pipeline/removefield
`{
    "description": "remove field",
    "processors": [
        {
            "foreach": {
                "field": "propertyMap",
                "processor": {
                    "remove": {
                        "field": "1"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
} `and it gave me this error now: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: field [propertyMap] of type [java.util.HashMap] cannot be cast to [java.util.List]",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with pipelines, but just as an alternative solution, have you considered the opposite approach (specifying which fields you want to keep)?

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "<source_index>",
    "_source": ["keep_field_1", "keep_field_2"]
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "<dest_index>"
  }
}
```

The list is probably a lot longer since you're around 1000 field limit, but you should be able to get it relatively easily from your mapping.

Comment: This doesn't work either. When I reindex, all the fields get copied to the new index, including the ones I don't specify in _source.

Comment: So your solution solved half of the problem. The main issue was dynamic mapping creation. I created a new index with `"index.mapper.dynamic": false` and then reindexed using the above approach and it worked perfectly.. Thanks for help!!